# Count number of successful processed messages on camel parallel split

Tags: java, apache-camel

I'm diggin' into camel, in order to process a lot of records in parallel. I have something like this:

```
     from(CAMEL_START_ROUTE_CTE)       
         .multicast().parallelProcessing()
            .to(CAMEL_PROCESS_DOMAINS_ROUTE)
            .to(CAMEL_PROCESS_OTHERS_ROUTE)
         .end()
         .onCompletion()
         .to(EndCamelRouteBuilder.CAMEL_ROUTE);
```

Where CAMEL_START_ROUTE_CTE is

```
timer:foo?delay=100&repeatCount=1
```

And then, CAMEL_PROCESS_DOMAINS_ROUTE looks like this:

```
 from(CAMEL_PROCESS_DOMAINS_ROUTE)
         .setHeader("domains").constant(config.getDomains())
             .split(header("domains"))          
             .parallelProcessing()
                .to(ProcessDomainCamelRoute.CAMEL_ROUTE)

             .end()
         .end();
```

Simplifying, domains is a json list.

What I'm trying to achieve is a way to count the number of messages and be able to read it in the route EndCamelRoute

I've tried with exchange.setProperty into the processor (using CamelSplitSize), setHeader, etc... but I always get a null when reading.

Does anybody know a way to achieve something like this? Some kind... of a reporting stuff (number of failed, successful messages), but consumed in a different route

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was fighting a similar issue while using split. Ended up having a very simple bean holding a hashmap where I store my counters.
I was looking into [MicroMeter Component](https://camel.apache.org/components/latest/micrometer-component.html) but it is consumer only.

Comment: Wow, thats a great solution!

I have been fighting with this since yesterday and I have managed to solve it using the AggregationStrategy.

It's a bit ugly, but works very well. I will post my solution as soon as I have a little spare time.

Thanks @Radovan!